# How to convert a date into a time period python

Tags: python, date, nlp

User case:

`June 2016(OR 06/2016) => 06/01/2016-06/30/216
June 2016 to Dec 2016(OR between June 2016 and Dec 2016) =>  06/01/2016-12/31/216`

I'm wondering if there a python library or API service I can call from python, so that I can translate date in a natural language into a standard time period like the above user case

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `dateutil` should help.

**Ex:**

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

s = 'June 2016(OR 06/2016)'
s = s.split("(OR")
start = parser.parse(s[0]).strftime("%m/01/%Y")
end = (parser.parse(start) + relativedelta(day=31)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print "{0}-{1}".format(start, end)
```

**Output:**

```
06/01/2016-06/30/2016
```